# Job Suspended Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login using Azure AutomationAccounts System Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-managed-identity, powershell-module

I am trying to shutdown the VM using Azure Automation Account **System Managed identity** option.

However I am ending up with below error.

[image]

As per the other articles it is mentioned to upgrade the module Update-ModulesInAutomationToLatestVersion but I could not update due to below error. I am not sure what is the issue in the script. Same script works with AzureRunAsConnection option without issues ( [script](https://gist.github.com/udaykiran34/65d5d7480fbc37c5eb8ef6509ba3f3ca) ).I even checked with simple login with System Managed Identity it successfully login and fetches the resource group names.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the above shared script in my automation account. Below are
the couple of observations:

1. You need to use `Connect-AzureRMAccount -Identity` cmdlet instead of 'connect-AzAccount` to connect to your subscription because the rest of the script that you have written using Azure RM cmdlets.
2. If we use `AzureRM` cmdlets in your run book script the job is getting suspended stating that Azure RM is going to retired and suggesting us to use `Az` Module in your workflow.
3. You can refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-8.0.0) on how to migrate your PowerShell scripts automatically from `AzureRM` to AZ modules.
4. If you want to perform start/stop on your virtual Machines you can leverage the [Azure Automation start/stop during the off hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management) feature.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management) and ***looking at your script the Azure Rm module is not supported and it has been updated to the latest version of [Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-azure-modules#update-az-modules)***.

[image]

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**|[***Using a system-assigned managed identity for an Azure Automation account***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation#enable-using-powershelly) & [***Troubleshoot runbook issue***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/runbooks#login-azurerm).